# Duda con return en funcion con condicionales

Tags: javascript, function

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde tengo que filtrar las ovejas de color rojo y que contengan 'a' y 'n'

Esta es mi solucion:

```js
const ovejas = [
  { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
  { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'},
  { name: 'AAAAAaaaaa', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Nnnnnnnn', color: 'rojo'},
  { name: 'Andrew', color: 'rojo' }
]

const ovejasFiltro = (arrOfObj) => {
    arrOfObj.forEach(object => {
  if(object.color === 'rojo' && object.name.includes('a') && object.name.includes('N') ){
console.log(object.name)}
})
    return true
}

console.log(ovejasFiltro(ovejas));
```

Este es mi problema:

No entiendo completamente como deberia usar el *return*. Si la condicion es *true*, ¿puedo retornar los objetos que cumplan con la condicion?
Si no se puede, como puedo hacer para que retorne *true* si se cumple la condicion o *false* en caso de que no lo haga?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres retornar los objetos o quieres retornar true o false? No me queda claro lo que quieres. Si quieres retornar los objetos que matcheen la condicion deberías usar un filter. Tu función quedaría basicamente `return ovejas.filter(o => o.color === 'rojo' && o.name.includes("N") &&  o.name.includes("a"))`. Un filter en un array siempre retorna todos los objetos en los que la condición devuelva true.

Comment: Si vas a filtrar manualmente un Array (sin usar el método `filter`) debes devolver un nuevo Array con los objetos que pasen el filtro o un Array vacío si ninguno lo pasa (tal como funciona el método `filter`). Lo de `true` y `false` parece que te enreda de haber leido la documentación de `filter`. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora me quedo mas claro, no tuve en cuenta ese metodo.